# Conditionally formatting multiple rows with the same conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to format 500+ rows of data and essentially, G5-K5 (in every row) needs to be highlighted a light color (any color) if J5 equals "Regular".

This same condition will exist in every row, so it should be simple - but I am not an excel master by any means. I just don't think it's necessary to create 500+ conditions for each row!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually pretty simple.

1. You right click one of the cells to do the formatting(one with
   regular for example)  and select Conditional Formatting on the menu.
2. Then you make sure the Range is the cell you right clicked, select
   "The text is exactly" in the list and type "Regular in the field
   under it.
3. Select the color under that field and press the blue button.
4. After that you just need to press the paint format tool(the paint
   roll) and drag all the cells you want to have the same
   behaviour(probably the entire column of the right clicked cell).

Comment: Perfect. Didn't realize there was a paint format tool!